# Help!! Understanding Register Addresses as well as addresses in ROM or RAM

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers

I'm looking at a memory map of a chip and I see that PORTA is assgined the address in hex 0000. PORTB has the address in hex 0001. PORTA has 8 pins which means it's 8 bits wide. PORTB has 8 pins which is 8 bits as well.

I know that each hex digit is 4 bits. In other words, the hex value FF is actually 8 bits wide because each digit is 4 bits. So does this mean that the memory location of PORTA 0000 is 16 bits wide and the memory location 0001 is also 16 bits wide.

I'm confused on how to interpret this. I thought every memory location whether it's in RAM or ROM or STACK is 8 bits wide except for like special registers like register X and Y and D which are 16 bit registers.

Can someone help me grasp a better intuitive understanding of this.

Comment: No, these registers are always 8-bits in size.  The addresses you quoted are actually offsets from the base port address.  Which is determined by the system builder.  Could be memory mapped or used on an I/O bus, the size of the address is a design choice.

Answer (score 1):

"PORTB has the address in hex 0001"
This is most likely an offset value, not an address.
Check the documentation for your device.

---

One hex digit is 4 bits. (for example 'F')
Hex is usually shown in groups of two characters because that is one byte. (1 byte = 8 bits)

So it takes one byte, or 8 bits to represent 'FF' in hex.

Reference wiki page [on hex here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).
Bin - Hex conversion [article here](http://www.computerhope.com/binhex.htm).